# Python discount function

Tags: python, function

This is a discount function in python that applies a discount to a specified price. You get a 10% discount if you are a member, and you get a 5% discount if the item is on sale.

```
def calculate_price(orig_price, is_member="Yes", is_on_sale="Yes"):
    member_discount = 0.10
    sale_discount = 0.05
    
    if is_member == True:
        if is_on_sale == True:
            price = orig_price - (orig_price * (member_discount + sale_discount))
        
        else:
            price = orig_price - (orig_price * member_discount)
        
    elif is_member == False:
        if is_on_sale == True:
            price = orig_price - (orig_price * sale_discount)
        else:
            price = orig_price
    return price

orig_price = float(input("Enter price: "))
is_member = input("Member? (yes or no): ")
is_on_sale = input("sale? (yes or no): ")

print(calculate_price(orig_price, is_member="yes", is_on_sale="yes"))
```

My problem is when I try to run it I get the error:

> File "", line 23, in    File "", line 17, in
> calculate_price UnboundLocalError: local variable 'price' referenced
> before assignment

Anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass "is_member" as a string "yes", yet your code assumes it is a boolean of True or False, consequently none of your code paths setting variable "price" executes. Unify your code to either pass booleans as is_member, or change the logic inside the function that compares "is_member" to a boolean to compare to a string of interest instead.